# simple way to put validation icon in input without bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi :) what is the best and simple way to put validation icon in input without bootstrap using jquery and support RTL

[something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP3HW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Without the addition of a font library (i.e. w/ raw CSS & HTML), you could try adding a Unicode [code point](https://codepoints.net/) such as:

```css
.success {
  font-style: normal;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.success:before {
  color: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: "\2611"; /* Unicode Ballot Box with Check */
}
```

```html
<i class="success">emailaddress@email.com</i>
```

**UPDATE:**

> If you need **right-to-left (rtl)** for the specific element, you can add `direction: rtl` to the CSS selector *OR* add `dir="rtl"` to the element or to one of its descendants.

Here is a simple [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/hbgyz42c/) using only HTML5 validation, CSS, and Unicode code points:

Comment: sorry i mean in input just like photo att.

Comment: @haitham - It depends on whether or not you want to use jQuery or JavaScript. One simple approach is with [HTML5 validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/). My personal favorite (if using jQuery) is [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)... and there is always raw [JS validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate/)